# apache2 mods svn and webdav differences

Tags: svn, apache-2.2, mod-webdav

Are those 2 mods supposed to be the same, do the same jobs or am i missing the big picture. What I want to achieve is have my subversion repos accessible from the web and be able work on them. Shall I go for mod svn or dav?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn is for version control - subversion

webdav is for web access on your files - no version control

Comment: To clarify, the dav_svn module does utilize WebDAV, but this is correct; mod_dav_svn is specifically for access to subversion repositories.

Comment: So i setup svn as usual and install mod_dav to access the repos from the web, is that right?

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/debian_subversion_websvn on how to do it on ubuntu  - this is for a rpm based (fedora etc) https://support.railsmachine.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=42